# How Can I Rename Certain File Extensions In A PHP Uploader?

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files, tmp

I am trying to make it so when a user uploads a .sh file it will change the file extension to .txt before it gets on my server. My current code is

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileRealExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
$uploadDirectory = "/uploads/";
$currentDirectory = getcwd();
$uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);
$newFileName = uniqid("", true)  . "." . $fileRealExt;
$fileTmpName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$fileUploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . $newFileName;
$notAllowed = array("sh");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if (in_array($fileRealExt, $notAllowed)) {
                $fileName = $fileExt[0] . ".txt";
                $newFileName = uniqid("", true)  . ".txt";
                $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileUploadPath);
                if ($didUpload) {
                        header("Location: $uploadDirectory$newFileName");
                } else{
                        header("Location: error.php");
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Right now what it does is the `header()` will take you to the randomized filename with the .txt extension but it will be there and it will not upload at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` uses `$fileUploadPath` as the destination, but that's defined before you try to do the renaming, so it still has its earlier value. Therefore you haven't removed the problem at all.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you I have fixed the problem